# Abrupt transition between views within a Navigation View

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm having trouble figuring out how to smoothly navigate from my SignInView() to my FirstView(). I have my FirstView() inside of a Navigation Stack, but the transition between the views is very abrupt and devoid of the transition that you normally get with the use of a NavigationLink. How can I get the transition to work?

Much appreciated!

Here is the relevant code...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationView {
                if viewModel.signedIn {
                    FirstView()
                        .transition(.slide)
                } else {
                    //.onAppear method is used for keyboard management (See Misc Functions...)
                    SignInView()
                        .onAppear(perform: UIApplication.shared.addTapGestureRecognizer)
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.listen()
            }
        }
        
    }
}



class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var userInfo: User?
    @Published var signedIn: Bool = false
    
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    let authRef = Auth.auth()
    
    var authHandle : AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    var rootInfoCollection : CollectionReference!
    var userIdRef = ""

    
    
    func fetchUserData(){
        db.collection("Users").document("\(userIdRef)").getDocument { document, error in
            // Check for error
            if error == nil {
                // Check that this document exists
                if document != nil && document!.exists {
                    
                    self.userInfo = document.map { (documentSnapshot) -> User in
                        let data = documentSnapshot.data()
                        
                        let uid = data?["uid"] as? UUID ?? UUID()
                        let company = data?["company"] as? String ?? ""
                        let name = data?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let admin = data?["admin"] as? Bool ?? false
                        let photo = data?["photo"] as? String ?? ""
                        
                        return User(uid: uid, company: company, name: name, admin: admin, photo: photo)
                    }
                    
                    withAnimation {
                        self.signedIn = true
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func listen(){
        handle = authRef.addStateDidChangeListener({ auth, user in
            print(user?.email ?? "No User Found")
            
            if let user = auth.currentUser {
                self.userIdRef = user.uid
                self.rootInfoCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("/Users/")
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.fetchUserData()
                }
                                
            } else {
                self.signedIn = false
            }
        })
        
    }
    
    func signIn(email: String, password: String){
        authRef.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            guard result != nil, error == nil else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}




struct SignInView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    
    @State private var username : String = ""
    @State private var password : String = ""
    @State private var shouldShowLoginAlert: Bool = false
    @State var selectedImageArray : [Image] = []
    
    var disableLoginButton : Bool {
        return self.username.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "awText"))
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 180, height: 100)
                .padding(.bottom, 50)
            
            TextField("Email", text: $username)
                .padding(.leading)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
            Rectangle().fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.25)).frame(height: 1, alignment: .center).padding(.bottom)
                .padding(.bottom)
                .onChange(of: self.username, perform: { value in
                    if value.count > 10 {
                        self.username = String(value.prefix(20)) //Max 10 Characters for Username.
                    }
                })
            
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .padding(.leading)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
            Rectangle().fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.25)).frame(height: 1, alignment: .center)
                .onChange(of: self.username, perform: { value in
                    if value.count > 10 {
                        self.username = String(value.prefix(10)) //Max 10 Characters for Password.
                    }
                })
            
            
            //SignIn Button
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.signIn(email: username, password: password)
            }, label: {
                Text("Sign In")
                    .disabled(disableLoginButton)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous))
                    .padding()
            })
}
```

Comment: Could you try to use a ```FirstView().transition(.slide)```? What do you think?

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately..

Comment: oups yes you need to use ```withAnimation```, someone posted an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the default `NavigationView` behavior with your own animations isn't necessarily totally straightforward. I'll lay out one possibility, but another would be to use a real `NavigationView` transition, but just hide the back button once you're on `FirstView`.

To do the transition yourself, you'll need *one* root element to `NavigationView`, an `if` clause, a `transition(.slide)` and `withAnimation`.  Here's a simplified version of your code showing just these elements:

```
class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var signedIn = false
}

struct FirstView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Signed in")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = AppViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if viewModel.signedIn {
                     FirstView()
                        .transition(.slide)
                } else {
                    Button("Sign me in") {
                        withAnimation {
                            viewModel.signedIn = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working either :(

Comment: @RapsIn4 the code that I provided works if you copy and paste it into Xcode. Can you identify what the difference was in your implementation?

Comment: I updated my code above to reflect your suggestions. Other than the use of Firebase, I don't see any differences in the code.

Comment: There's a significant difference -- look at the order of `VStack` and `NavigationView`

Comment: lol that was it! Can't believe I missed that. I really appreciate you helping me with this. Thank you!